# Где найти обновления Андроид?

Tags: android

Часто встречаю в новостях что Гугл выпустил обновления для Андроид. К примеру,

> Августовские плановые обновления для Android исправляют три уязвимости в файловой системе F2FS.

Вот вопрос, а где, собственно, взять эти обновления и как установить их? Если телефон поначалу сам обновлялся, то теперь уже последний год он не обновляется. Т.к производители прекратили поддержку. Информации, где брать эти обновления не нашёл, только предложения ставить другую прошивку, где эти обновления уже есть. В общем, можно ли где-то найти обновления и ставить их самому?

Comment: в общем случае - нет. Если у Вас Nexus/Pixel, тогда обновления прилетят сами (если только телефон не старше 18 месяцев (или дату продлили, надо уточнить)). Если же телефон от China Noname, тогда скорее всего никак. Либо искать стороннюю прошивку.

Comment: @KoVadim - даже Samsung редко поддерживает свои устройства дольше чем полгода. Чего уж говорить о China Noname.

Comment: Зато ЧайнаНонаме продается по всему миру огромными тиражами, не имеет залочек бутлоадеров и вообще рут из коробки, потому наверняка найдется ВасянСупер666, который прочитав пару книжек по кишкам Андроида, сможет сделать свою прошивку. И таким образом у вас будет "поддержка" значительно дольше, чем у "флагманов".

Comment: @bukkojot ВасянСупер666 = bukkojot ? =)

Comment: Вопрос очень актуальный, потому что сильно удручает то, что телефон, который полностью устраивает по железу, приходится менять просто потому что на него вдруг решили больше не выпускать обновления. Раньше был Cyanogen, но теперь его закрыли. А LineageOS, которая вместо него, еще неизвестно, будет развиваться или помрет потихоньку.

Answer (score 1):

Устранение уязвимостей в Android - это результат работы разработчика над ядром. Новые версии ядра постепенно становятся несовместимыми с более старым железом. Новые версии Android официально не ставятся на более старые модели телефонов. Можно делать root, ставить кастомные прошивки и так далее, но иногда это вызывает проблемы: например, определенное ПО не ставится, если оно видит не тот ROM.

Что касается устранения уязвимости файловой системы и подобные исправления, это ведь не отражается на вашем удобстве использования. Это в большей степени прививка, которую нужно поставить на максимальное количество устройств, чтобы уязвимостью не воспользовались хакеры. Поэтому я предлагаю не искать обновления для Android.